# R, difference of SARIMA and ARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, arima

**I ran the following code:**

```
sarima(data,0,0,1,0,1,1, 12) # p=0,d=0,q=1; P=0,D=12,Q=1
initial  value -3.812739 
iter   2 value -4.161744
iter   3 value -4.243969
iter   4 value -4.245956
iter   5 value -4.248315
iter   6 value -4.249812
iter   7 value -4.249835
iter   8 value -4.249836
iter   8 value -4.249836
final  value -4.249836 
converged
initial  value -4.241929 
iter   2 value -4.244114
iter   3 value -4.245877
iter   4 value -4.253871
iter   5 value -4.254046
iter   6 value -4.254069
iter   6 value -4.254069
iter   6 value -4.254069
final  value -4.254069 
converged
$fit

Call:
stats::arima(x = xdata, order = c(p, d, q), seasonal = list(order = c(P, D, 
    Q), period = S), xreg = constant, optim.control = list(trace = trc, REPORT = 1, 
    reltol = tol))

Coefficients:
          ma1     sma1  constant
      -0.2273  -1.0000     0e+00
s.e.   0.0811   0.0659     1e-04

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0001628:  log likelihood = 405.42,  aic = -802.85

$degrees_of_freedom
[1] 152

$ttable
         Estimate     SE  t.value p.value
ma1       -0.2273 0.0811  -2.8043  0.0057
sma1      -1.0000 0.0659 -15.1674  0.0000
constant   0.0000 0.0001  -0.0114  0.9909

$AIC
[1] -7.684481

$AICc
[1] -7.669857

$BIC
[1] -8.625576
```

**and then I run the below code:**

```
arima(data, order =c(0,0,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,1), period = 12))
Call:
arima(x = data, order = c(0, 0, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 12))

Coefficients:
          ma1     sma1
      -0.2272  -1.0000
s.e.   0.0810   0.0659

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0001628:  log likelihood = 405.42,  aic = -804.84
```

I think both function fit p=0,d=0,q=1; P=0,D=12,Q=1 but why the AIC from these two functions are different? For SARIMA, AIC = -7.68 while for ARIMA, AIC is -804.84

I am just trying to fit different sarima models and compare aic to find the best model, and I'm not very clear about what's the difference between these two functions SARIMA and ARIMA.

Thanks

Comment: I notice that in SARIMA, there is a aic=-802.85 and there is another one $AIC [1] -7.684481

Comment: what are these two AIC mean?

Comment: I added the tag, it is run in R language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more information from Shumway & Stoffer's [Time Series Analysis and Its Applications With R Examples](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/). I provide answer to your question with references directly from their Chapter 2. The authors define their AIC with the formula below:

**Definition 2.1 Akaike’s Information Criterion (AIC)**
$$
AIC = log\ \hat{\sigma}_k + \frac{n + 2k}{n}
$$

where $\hat{\sigma}_k $ is $\frac{SSE_k}{n}$ and $k$ is the number of parameters in the model.

However, this calculation of AIC is different from R's `lm`. In your example, the AIC with the value of -802.85 is from R, whereas the AIC of -7.684481 is derived from R's results with additional adjustment to fit Definition 2.1.

On page 56 of Shumway & Stoffer, they provide how their AIC can be derived:

> The easiest way to extract AIC and BIC from an lm() run in R is to use the command AIC(). Our definitions differ from R by terms that do not change from model to model. In the example, we show how to obtain (2.19) and (2.21) from the R output. It is more difficult to obtain AICc.

```
num = length(cmort) # sample size
AIC(fit)/num - log(2*pi) # AIC
```

In your case, 
$$
\frac{-802.85}{\text{Sample Size}} - log(2\pi)
$$

or the code below

```
AIC(sarima(data,0,0,1,0,1,1, 12)$fit)/length(data) - log(2*pi)
```

should return the value of -7.684481.

I have experimented the two AICs with a different dataset and was able to get somewhat close (but not exact) results. But this is what the authors have said about the two values.